# Using ng-click and ng-swipe on the same element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-touch

Using the 1.3 is it possible to make something like this work

```html
<thumbnail                                                                      
    ng-click="playVideo(video.position)"                                         
    ng-swipe-left="move(2)"
    ng-swipe-right="move(-2)"
></thumbnail>
```

When I try it only the swipes fire